# How do you convert POSIX date to day of year?

Tags: r, datetime

The title has it: how do you convert a POSIX date to day-of-year?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

An alternative is to format the `"POSIXt"` object using `strftime()`:

```
R> today <- Sys.time()
R> today
[1] "2012-10-19 19:12:04 BST"
R> doy <- strftime(today, format = "%j")
R> doy
[1] "293"
R> as.numeric(doy)
[1] 293
```

which is preferable to remembering that the day of the years is zero-based in the POSIX standard.

Comment: Just ran into my first data set with a `POSIXct` column. Seemed like time to mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Gavin, is it also possible to convert a date to days since a specified data, e.g.number of days since March 1st 2015?  I can also post as a new question...

Comment: @B.Davis You can do something like `as.numeric(Sys.Date()-as.Date('2015-03-01',format='%Y-%m-%d'))`

Answer (score 38):

As `?POSIXlt` reveals, a `$yday` suffix to a `POSIXlt` date (or even a vector of such) will convert to day of year. Beware that POSIX counts Jan 1 as day 0, so you might want to add 1 to the result.

It took me embarrassingly long to find this, so I thought I'd [ask and answer my own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Alternatively, the excellent `lubridate` package provides the `yday` function, which is just a wrapper for the above method. It conveniently defines similar functions for other units (`month`, `year`, `hour`, ...).

```
today <- Sys.time()
yday(today)
```

Comment: Part of why it took me so long is that if `d` is a POSIXlt object, `str(d)` gives no indication that `d` has any further attributes. This, and that the `$` operator works element-wise on a vector of POSIXlt objects means more than just a usual extraction is going on. I'd be interested in reading a bit more about that if anyone can recommend a nice place to start.

Comment: And, to respond to my own comment, `attributes` is the command I was looking for, `attributes(d)` provides all the ways of displaying `d`.

Comment: Heh, I was struggling with this question too. Seems that you answered it yourself (as opposed to just doing it without posting it here). Thanks for that!

Comment: Note that this will only work with an object of class `"POSIXlt"`. The other major class is `"POSIXct"` and that is stored internally in a very different way. Try your method on the output of `Sys.time()` for example. The `strftime()` approach works with both types.

Comment: A warning from my side. Remember to use `yday` on POSIXct object only! `yday` runs on character without any error message, moreover giving reasonable doy number. However, these doy will be wrong.

Comment: @FraNut I'm not sure really what you're saying. Lubridate's `yday()` works very well on `POSIXct`, `POSIXlt` and `Date` class. It also works  on `character` in standard formats, e.g., `yday("2020-01-10")` gives 10, and `yday("2020-12-10")` gives 345, both are correct. If you have an example of running `yday` on a character and getting  reasonable but wrong doy numbers, please show an example and consider filing a bug on `lubridate` github.

Comment: @GregorThomas, if I run `yday("15/06/2021")` on my Rstudio I get `171`, while the correct answer is `166`. No error message is showed. Thanks for the hint on character in standard formats. Maybe slash is the issue. The absence of an error message and the fact the result seems reasonable is really tricky tough.

Comment: @FraNut The not-YMD format is the issue. Internally, lubridate will run `as.Date("15/06/2021")`, which happily returns "0015-06-20", assuming year, month, day (with some extra). You're right that you shouldn't just assume date conversions on character strings work, but "only POSIXct" is much too far in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 4):

I realize it isn't quite what the poster was looking for, but I needed to convert POSIX date-*times* into a *fractional* day of the year for time series analysis and ended up doing this:

```
today <- Sys.time()

doy2015f<-difftime(today,as.POSIXct(as.Date("2015-01-01 00:00", tzone="GMT")),units='days')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package also provides a `yday()` function.

```r
require(data.table)
today <- Sys.time()
yday(today)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how I do it:

```
as.POSIXlt(c("15.4", "10.5", "15.5", "10.6"), format = "%d.%m")$yday
# [1] 104 129 134 160
```

Comment: Works well for `POSIXlt` (as mentioned in my answer), but not for `POSIXct` objects. E.g., `Sys.time()$yday` doesn't work.