# Transform year/week colnames into date in r

Tags: r, date, yearmonth

I have the following columns' names of dataframe in year/week format

```
cols = colnames(vci1981.df)

 [1] "gid"     "xcoord"  "ycoord"  "col"     "row"     "gwno"    "country" "km2"     "1981035" "1981036"
[11] "1981037" "1981038" "1981039" "1981040" "1981041" "1981042" "1981043" "1981044" "1981045" "1981046"
[21] "1981047" "1981048" "1981049" "1981050" "1981051" "1981052"
```

Note: year 1981- week 0xx

**How can I transform them into the corresponding year-month format please ?**

Example: 1981-035 = 1981-08

I tried the same method as here [Transform year/day colnames into date in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72792632/transform-year-day-colnames-into-date-in-r)
without success.

```
cols = ymd(parse_date_time(cols[9:length(cols)], orders="yw"))
```

I got NA here.

and

```
cols = as.Date(cols[9:length(cols)], "%Y%W")
```

I got non corresponding values here:
[1] "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29"
[9] "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29"
[17] "1981-06-29" "1981-06-29"

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
## Creating the Dataframe
cols = c( "gid","xcoord","ycoord","col","row","gwno","country","km2","1981035","1981036",
       "1981037","1981038","1981039","1981040","1981041","1981042","1981043","1981044","1981045",
       "1981046","1981047","1981048","1981049","1981050","1981051","1981052"
)
df = data.frame(ColNames = cols)

## Creating empty list
df1=list()
df2=list()

## For loop to extract the year and the week
for (i in 9:nrow(df)){
  a = substring(df$ColNames[i],1,4)
  b = substring(df$ColNames[i],5,nchar(df$ColNames[i]))
  df1 = append(df1,a)
  df2 = append(df2,b)
}

## unlisting all lists
df1=unlist(df1)
df2=unlist(df2)

## Converting month number to digit month number
df2 = sprintf("%02d",sapply(strsplit(df2, ''), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))))


## Replacing original values with new formatted values
cols[9:length(cols)] = paste(df1,"-",df2, sep="")
```

### Output

```
> cols
 [1] "gid"     "xcoord"  "ycoord"  "col"     "row"     "gwno"    "country" "km2"     "1981-08" "1981-09" "1981-10" "1981-11" "1981-12"
[14] "1981-04" "1981-05" "1981-06" "1981-07" "1981-08" "1981-09" "1981-10" "1981-11" "1981-12" "1981-13" "1981-05" "1981-06" "1981-07"
```

Comment: Hello! If this answer meets your requirement, please consider clicking the tick mark on the left side to accept the answer. This will help the other users who are struggling with the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: when I try to work with the data I have a problem.                                                cols = cols[9:length(cols)] = paste(df1,"-",df2, sep="")
names(vci1981.df[9:26]) = paste(cols)
Then: vci1981.df2 = pivot_longer(
  vci1981.df,
  cols = c(9:26)) and I got the following message "Error in `loc_validate()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, … don't exist.
ℹ There are only 18 columns.    "                                                                                       Do you know why?

Comment: Is it possible that you could share a subset of your data like first 6 rows? You could put it on a google drive and share the link here in comments and I can see and resolve the issue. @MyrTH

Comment: Sure, here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mgIEs3JBqFbUIsP4KO1no-6DKNJhkbq6IHX86jM_dN0/edit

Comment: @MyrTH I just sent you request for access.

Comment: Try this: ```df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(gid,xcoord,ycoord,col,row,gwno,country,km2), names_to="Year-Week",values_to = "Values")``` where df is your dataset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246080/discussion-between-deepansh-arora-and-myr-th).

Comment: Unfortunately, the dates are wrong. It starts well but then it goes messy. So I have found a way. I first, replace the '0' between the year and the week by a dash. Then: as.Date(str_c(cols, "-1"), format="%Y-%U-%u") as related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549449/transform-year-week-to-date-object/45587644#45587644. My only concern, is that I would have preferred an ISO format but could not find a way regarding my context.