# R convert date column into gregorian calendar

Tags: r, gregorian-calendar

I would like to convert a column of a dataframe into gregorian date.
For example the following dataframe:

```
       Date_R Tmax
1  1985-01-01  9.0
2  1985-02-02  9.0
3  1985-12-31 11.0
4  1986-01-04  8.5
5  1986-01-05 11.0
```

Into:

```
  Date_R Tmax
1      1  9.0
2     33  9.0
3    365 11.0
4      4  8.5
5      5 11.0
```

Or add a new column with this information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958298/how-do-you-convert-posix-date-to-day-of-year-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you can use `as.POSIXlt`

```
as.POSIXlt(df$Date_R)$yday + 1L
## [1]   1  33 365   4   5
```

Answer (score 7):

Convert the 'Date_R' column to 'Date' class (if not), and `format` with option `%j` to get the day of the year.

```
 df1$Date_R <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(df1$Date_R), '%j'))
 df1
 #  Date_R Tmax
 #1      1  9.0
 #2     33  9.0
 #3    365 11.0
 #4      4  8.5
 #5      5 11.0
```