# How to calculate the index of a day with respect to 365 days of the year?

Tags: r

I have a data frame of daily dates from December 2018, until March 2019, and I need to find the "Index of the day" because it is the input of another function to calculate time and sunset.

The "Index of the day" is the number of days compared to the other days of the year. Example.- January 5 (5 of 365); February 1 (32 of 365), etc.

Comment: so you need day of the year from date ? Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958298/how-do-you-convert-posix-date-to-day-of-year-in-r

Comment: You can try `days <- as.Date(c("01-01-2010", "01-10-2010"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
format(days, "%j")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `yday` function in the lubridate package.

```
lubridate::yday(ymd('2019-09-04')) #247
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),as.Date(paste0(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"),'-01-01')),units = "days"))
```

For today the result is

246